# ASP - Remove duplicate words from a string

Tags: asp-classic

**Classic ASP**

My string contains duplicate words like this:

```
myString = "cat dog dog mouse dog cat dog"
```

...and I need to reconstruct the string to look like `"cat dog mouse"`, doesn't really matter what order the string ends up, although I would prefer to keep the first instances in the same order as the original string.

Without writing 20 lines of code, is there a more efficient method I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I want to show two methods.
**Using Dictionary Object Keys**

```vb
myString = "cat dog dog mouse dog cat dog"
Set oDict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
oDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each word In Split(myString, " ")
    oDict(word) = Null
Next
Response.Write(Join(oDict.Keys, " "))
Set oDict = Nothing
```

**string concatenation**

```vb
myString = "cat dog dog mouse dog cat dog"
arrWords = Split(myString, " ")
sTmp = " "
For Each word In arrWords
    If word <> "" And InStr(1, sTmp, " " & word & " ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then _
    sTmp = sTmp & word & " "
Next
Response.Write(Trim(sTmp))
```

I would prefer the first one.
**Note**: All comparisons are case insensitive. You need to change all **vbTextCompare** constants to **vbBinaryCompare** if you want make case sensitive comparisons.

Comment: First example worked ok, but the second failed. I used the first one.